# Who will buy fine clothing?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am carrying a lot of fine clothing (boots, hats clothes) that is not stolen and want to sell it, buy I cannot find a buyer.  I do not have high speech skills yet.

Who can I sell them to in the early game?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any **general goods merchant** (signage usually consists of a balance scale), **spell merchant** (typically a court wizard or one of the instructors at the College of Winterhold), and **Radiant Raiment** in Solitude (signage shows a needle with thread) will purchase both fine and common clothing, according to [UESP](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Merchants).

For very early players, the **Riverwood Trader** is probably one of the more convenient options.  You could also sell to **Belethor's Shop** in Whiterun, or **Farengar Secret-Fire** (the court wizard of Whiterun, who you will meet as part of the main quest).

Comment: For early players, Belethor's General Goods shop in Whiterun is a good choice as well.